# Refrescar o redirigir una pagina en ejecucion

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras, tengo la tabla de productos formada, con los valores que voy agregando en una variable de sesion.. el problema es que cada vez que agrego un producto, me manda la comienzo de pagina,y me gustaria que o bien me mande a cada div, o solo me refresque la tabla de carrito (que esta debajo de la de productos en este momento)

Esta es la pagina de inicio, donde estan las dos tablas:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conectar.php");  
$link = Conectarse();


if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) 
{
    $carrito=$_SESSION['carrito'];
}
else
{
    $carrito=false;
}

?> 

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
<table class='Table table-striped' style="float:left">
    <thead>  
        <tr>;  
            <th scope="col">Codigo</th>  
            <th scope="col">Producto</th>  
            <th scope="col">Comentario</th>  
            <th scope="col">Precio</th>
            <th scope="col">Agregar al carro</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
<?php
include ("carrito.php");

    foreach ($link->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY codigo") as $row)
    {   
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<div id='".$row["codigo"]."'>";
        echo "<th scope='row'>".$row["codigo"]."</th>";
        $cod=$row["codigo"];
        echo "<td>".$row["producto"]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>$".$row["precio"]."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='agregarproducto.php?codigo=$cod'><i class='fa fa-cart-plus fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i> </td>";  
        echo "</div>";   
        echo "</tr>";  
    }
?>
    </tbody>  
</table> 
</div>



<table class='Table table-striped'>
<thread>
    <tr>
            <th scope="col">Producto</th>  
            <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>  
            <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
            <th scope="col">Precio total</th>  
            <th scope="col">Eliminar del carro</th>  
    </tr>
</thread>
    <tbody>
<?php
    $carrito=$_SESSION["carrito"];
    $total=0;
    foreach ($carrito as $car) 
    {
        echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<th scope='row'>".$car["producto"]."</th>";
        echo "<td>".$car["cantidad"]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>$".$car["precio"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>$".$car["precio"]*$car["cantidad"]."</td>";
        $total=$total+($car["precio"]*$car["cantidad"]);
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i> </td>";     
        echo "</tr>";  
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>Precio total: $".$total."</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y esta es la clase carrito, para agregar cada uno (a traves de una pagina que solo instancia dicha clase):

```
<?php

class carrito
{
    public function agregarProducto()
    {
        session_start();
        include_once ("conectar.php");
        $link = Conectarse();
        $id=$_GET["codigo"];

        if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']))
        {
            $carrito=$_SESSION['carrito'];
        }

        $carrito=$_SESSION['carrito'];
        $cantidad=$carrito[$id]['cantidad']+1;

        $consulta=("select * from productos where codigo=$id");
        $pro=$link->query($consulta);

        $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($pro);

        $carrito[$id]=array($id,'cantidad'=>$cantidad,'producto'=>$fila['producto'],'precio'=>$fila['precio'],'id'=>$id);

        $_SESSION['carrito']=$carrito;

        header("location:inicio.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo:

1) Utilices el evento .click para capturar cuando el usuario presioné en agregar item al carrito (e igualmente cuando presione eliminar es otro evento .click).

2) Crear un div ("items_carrito") que contendrá la tabla donde muestras los items "adheridos" al carrito o sencillamente los que posee el carrito en el momento.

3) Utilizar la función .load de jquery para "refrescar" o "recargar" el contenido del `<div id="items_carrito"></div>` con la información nueva que el usario está agregando.

Para referenciarte en como hacer todo esto visita [jquery load](http://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-load-html-div-460/). Te servirá explicitamente el ejemplo 1 mostrado en esa página web.

Eso es todo. Un Saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy amplia tu pregunta, pero usa JS para cargar tu carro, en una div que se llame carro, cuando se agregue solo envia la peticion a tu servidor y el te enviará los datos y creas tu carro y lo guardas en ese div mediante Jquery o JS